# elementAtOrNull in Dart throwing an Exception

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

Why does this method throw an Exception if its a negative index?

```
list.elementAtOrNull(-1)
```

For example, identical code in Kotlin would return null.

Just wondering if there was a specific reason it was implemented to throw on a negative index?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the internal code for that function, it's as follows:

```
E? elementAtOrNull(int index) => (index < length) ? this[index] : null;
```

As you can see, it's only checking if the given index is smaller than the length of the list. Since -1 is smaller in any case, the call `this[-1]` throws exception.

Comment: This is the reason it throws, but I'm wondering why its implemented like that.

Comment: I guess the negative indexing is unsupported in general, so it makes sense that it throws